# Filtro com select utilizando JavaScript e php

Tags: php, javascript, pdo

Oi, estou tentando fazer um filtro de acordo com a opção que é escolhida em um `<select>`. Tenho um botão que executa a função criada no javascript. Tenho variáveis declaradas no php, e gostaria de saber como utiliza-las no javascript... Quando eu chamo elas diretamente no meu "< h3 >" vem com o valor correto, não sei onde estou errando na função para chamar de acordo com o select. Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficaria grato.

Esse é meu código: PHP (Tenho noção que as 4 variaveis com "pdo" tem o mesmo destino, só deixei preparado para quando for consultar os outros db)

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:C:Desktop\dashboard.db') or die("Erro ao abrir a base");

$pdo1 = new PDO('sqlite:C:Desktop\dashboard.db') or die("Erro ao abrir a base");
$pdo2 = new PDO('sqlite:C:Desktop\dashboard.db') or die("Erro ao abrir a base");
$pdo3 = new PDO('sqlite:C:Desktop\dashboard.db') or die("Erro ao abrir a base");
$pdo4 = new PDO('sqlite:C:Desktop\dashboard.db') or die("Erro ao abrir a base");

$regiao1NRows = $pdo1->query('SELECT count(*) from DEVICES')->fetchColumn();
$regiao2NRows = $pdo2->query('SELECT count(*) from DEVICES')->fetchColumn();
$regiao3NRows = $pdo3->query('SELECT count(*) from DEVICES')->fetchColumn();
$regiao4NRows = $pdo4->query('SELECT count(*) from DEVICES')->fetchColumn();

$totalNRows = $regiao1NRows+$regiao2NRows+$regiao3NRows+$regiao4NRows;

//var_dump($totalNRows);

?>
```

Esse é o HTML que possui o select e o botão que chama a função... :

```
<header class="container">

  <label for="regiao_filtro">Selecione a região:</label>
  <select onchange="filtroregiao(this)" id="regiao_filtro">
    <option value="regiaoTodos">Todas</option>
    <option value="regiao1">1</option>
    <option value="regiao2">2</option>
    <option value="regiao3">3</option>
    <option value="regiao4">4</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit" onclick="filtroregiao()" value="Pesquisa">Pesquisar</button>
```

```
      <h3 id="devicesCaptados"></h3>
```

Aqui é o JavaScript com a função e as comparações:

```
function filtroregiao(){

let regiao  = $(".regiao_filtro").val();
let dados = document.getElementById('devicesCaptados');

if(regiao == "Todos"){
dados = $totalNRows;
}else if(regiao == "regiao1"){
dados = $regiao1NRows;
}else if(regiao == "regiao2"){
dados = $regiao2NRows;
}else if(regiao == "regiao3"){
dados = $regiao3NRows;
}else if(regiao == "regiao4"){
dados = $regiao4NRows;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Então ao invés de clicar no botão para enviar a requisição porque você não tenta usar um onchange() no select, saca só:

HTML:

```
<label for="regiao_filtro">Selecione a região:</label>
<select onchange="filtroregiao(this)" id="regiao_filtro">
    <option value="regiaoTodos">Todas</option>
    <option value="regiao1">1</option>
    <option value="regiao2">2</option>
    <option value="regiao3">3</option>
    <option value="regiao4">4</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

```
function filtroregiao(){

let regiao  = $("#method").val();
let dados = document.getElementById('devicesCaptados');

if(regiao == "regiaoTodos"){
    fetch(`sua/api?dados=` + regiao) //Utiliza Fecth para fazer a requisição para seu script php
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) { //Caso o servidor devolva outro status HTTP que não for 200
                alert("Aconteceu um erro");
                return;
            }

            response.json().then(function (data) { //Pega os dados retornados em formato JSON
                dados.innerHTML = data;
            })
        }).catch(function (err) { // Tratamento de erro caso a URL der problema
        console.log("Error", err);
    })

} else {

}
```

}

Para começar a padronizar seus código comece a devolver a resposta sempre em JSON será mais fácil para tratar erros e respostas.

E no lugar do var_dump use print_r()

Comment: Poderia me fazer uma definição do funcionamento dessa propriedade chamada "FETCH" dentro da função que você citou? Ela estaria relacionada com o banco de dados? Pois eu estou acessando os dados do banco por um arquivo SQLite3 e utilizando pdo para isso... Valeu pela atenção

Comment: Aqui explicar melhor sobre o Fetch [Usando Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)